# C#, splitting serial data and displaying in separate textBox's

Tags: c#, split, serial-communication

I have the following code and i would like to split the incoming serial data into pieces and display the individual parts in separate textboxes. The incoming serial data is

- `angle1:angle2:value1:value2:value3:value4`

where

- `angle1` has values ranging from -90 to 90
- `angle2` ranges from 0 to 90
- `value1` `value2` `value3` `value4` from 0 to 1024

So I would like to display each of these in different textboxes.

This is what I have so far which displays the whole incoming string in a single textbox.

Any help, idea and tip is highly appreciated since I'm a complete newbie to c#.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port;

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private BackgroundWorker hardWorker;
        private Thread readThread = null;

        public Form1() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            hardWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (this.receiveText.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                //this.receiveText.Text += "";
                this.receiveText.Text += text;
                this.receiveText.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        public void Read()
        {
            while (serialPort2.IsOpen)
            {
                try{
                    if (serialPort2.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        string message = serialPort2.ReadLine();
                        this.SetText(message);
                    }
                }
                catch (TimeoutException) { }
            }
        }

        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();   

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                string port = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
                serialPort2.PortName = port;
                serialPort2.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort2.DtrEnable = true;
                serialPort2.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                serialPort2.WriteTimeout = 500;
                serialPort2.Open();
                readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Read));
                readThread.Start();
                this.hardWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void receiveText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            receiveText.SelectionStart = receiveText.Text.Length;
            receiveText.ScrollToCaret();
            receiveText.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

SOLVED by changing the following:

```
private void SetText(string text)
  {
    if (this.receiveText.InvokeRequired)
      {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
      }
    else
      {
        string[] newData = text.Split(':');
        boxLR.Text = newData[0];
        boxUD.Text = newData[1];
        boxldrright.Text = newData[2];
        boxldrleft.Text = newData[3];
        boxldrup.Text = newData[4];
        boxldrdown.Text = newData[5];
      }
  }
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Haven't read your all of your code but doesn't split(:) solves your problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, you need to split your string to get all different values as individual string.
In your SetText() function;

```
  string[] slist = text.Split(':');
```

Now if you have all required text box then you can assign value for string array to different text box.

Or else

if you are creating text box runtime then you have to create new text box as per length of slist array, then assign value to new text boxes.

Hope it helps..!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **this.receivedText.Text.[Split(':')](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** function to split the received text string into an array of string, which you then can use to assign to the different text boxes individually.

In addition to this, you could also create a method, that takes the array as a parameter, to check the various value constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the values are the same you can use
public void CopyTo( int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex, int count )